# MySQL won't connect to docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker

I am currently working on a school project and need to connect my code in Visual Studio Code to MySQL and Docker. But when i try and connect it to the database, it gives me an Access denied for Using password YES. I can't seem to find a solution. I tried rebuilding my database and recreated my MySQL file but nothing seems to work. I'll provide some screenshots of my code for context, but is there someone who can help me with this problem?
Toby Oldenburg
[image: These are the MySQL settings]
[image: This is the error]
[image: This is the code of the docker database build]
[image: This is my docker-compose code/file]
[image: This is the code for the schema in MySQL]
[image: The rest of MySQL]

I tried rebuilding the database, changing my code, changing the MySQL setting and checked my docker file a few times. Unfortunately nothing worked.

Comment: images are not allowed see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What doesn't really come accross for me is, from where you're trying to connect to the mysql. So mysql is in a container and you are trying to reach it from...?